# Issue with returning an array of type int from function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I have read through a lot of posts giving ways in which you can return an array of type int from a function. I have attempted to follow the approach of dynamically allocating the memory inside of the function using the `malloc()` function.

In the example code, I am using a function `foo` which calculates peaks in an array which are greater than a specified value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* function declaration */
int *foo(int arr[],int size);
int main()
{
int test[] = {1,2,1,4,5,2,7,8,9,1}; //array of test data.
int *p;
p = foo(test,10);
int w;
for(w=0;w<5;w++)
    {
      printf(" Peak %d\t",p[w]); // This line is giving a non sensible answer.
    }
    free(p); // free the memory

return 0;
}

int *foo(int arr[],int size) {
    int j;
    int Peak_min = 3; // Minimum peak height
    int *ret = malloc(size * sizeof(*ret));
    if(!ret)  return 1;
    for (j = 0; j < size -1; ++j)
    {
        if ( (arr[j] < arr[j+1]) && (arr[j+1] > arr[j+2]) && (arr[j+1] > Peak_min))// Peak criteria
        {
            ret[j] = arr[j+1];
            printf(" Peak_No %d",ret[j]); // This line is giving the correct output.            
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The output printed in the function gives 5 and 9, as expected. However, the output when I call the function in `int main()` gives non-sensible values. I am struggling to find the error with my code, any suggestions on how I can debug/fix this?

**Update**

I edited the for loop in the fucntion foo to

```
for (j = 0; j < size -2; ++j)
    {
        if ( (arr[j] < arr[j+1]) && (arr[j+1] > arr[j+2]) && (arr[j+1] > Peak_min))// Peak criteria
        {
            ret[j] = arr[j+1];
            printf(" Peak_No %d",ret[j]); // This line is giving the correct output.
        }
        else
        {
         ret[j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

I am now getting the output I wanted.

Comment: If the allocation in the `foo` function fails you should return a null pointer.

Comment: So change the return value 1 to NULL?

Comment: As for one part of the problem, when `j` equals `size - 2`, what happens when you do `arr[j+2]`?

Comment: Also, `malloc` does not initialize the memory it allocates, it contents will be *indeterminate*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are asking me. In the loop, j takes on values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I don't see the problem with this?

Comment: Yes and when `j` is `8` then `j + 2` is `10`. Which is out of bounds of an array of ten elements!

Comment: Ah Of course! @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc()` returns unitialized memory.

Inside the function, the assignment of `ret[j]` is *conditional*. You never know for sure that which or any index element is actually initialized. After returning the pointer, you unconditionally index into the pointer any to read the values which may be very well unitialized.

In case, you are returning the pointer with the same assignment condition, you can at least use `calloc()` which returns 0-filled memory, so at least, you have a deterministic value. However, this will fail to differentiate between a left-over index element and an element actually having a value of 0. For better precision, you can `memset()` the `malloc()`-ed memory to some guard value which indicates that those node values are not assigned.

Also, another *quickfix* would be, add one `else` condition which basically helps to unconditionally assign a value to each element.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? How can I modify this to ensure that the values will always be initialized?

Comment: @Sjoseph better now?

Comment: I am very new to memory allocation as I have really only used MATLAB until very recently! I am slowly starting to absorb the information and will read up on memset()  and calloc() now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the loop must be:

```
    int k= 0;
    for (j = 0; j < size -2; ++j)
    {
        if ( (arr[j] < arr[j+1]) && (arr[j+1] > arr[j+2]) && (arr[j+1] > Peak_min))// Peak criteria
        {
            ret[k++] = arr[j+1];
        }
    }
    ret[k]= 0;
    return ret;
}
```

and in main:

```
    int w= 0;
    while (p[w]) printf(" Peak %d\t",p[w++]);
```

This creates a list of peaks, terminated with a null entry.

Comment: I tried implementing the above change and seem to be caught in an infinite loop!

Comment: Oops, yeah, infinite loop. Should have been `printf(" Peak %d\t",p[w++]);` Note the `++`. Couldn't you spot & fix that yourself???

Comment: I opted back to work on my original attempt instead, but thanks for your useful comment